# Is there a "better" (signal-based) language for artificial intelligence

Tags: neural-networks, ai-design, programming-languages, signal-processing

I assume, there must be "signal-driven" and maybe also real-time programming language, which based on connectivy-data more than variables (int, string, etc).

I would like to have a language without equaton (x=4) but more like "x related to 4" or "cat related to animal" etc...

Comment: Consider what similarity means. Similarity is a metric which is going to be calculated mathematically. Even if you are using bins intuitively, that is in essence, a quantized set.

Answer (score 3):

- What You need are other ways of [knowledge representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_representation_and_reasoning), such as semantic networks or conceptual graphs. there you can define any possible relation between your entities. the knowledge of "x related to 4" exactly fits into "frames" and "semantic networks".
- [Jaynes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwin_Thompson_Jaynes) in his book,discusses thoroughly what "plausibility" means and why we need to take into account weak syllogisms and start using probability theory as a platform for developing a (general) AI. this might also help with your "reasoning" phase (after you've developed your knowledge base)

Comment: jaynes' idea is very clever, but i am missing a language like c++/java but signal-based and can handle millions of neuron-like classes. I thought there will be a special language for this.

Comment: @Andy Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHDL) out. (Specifically as an answer to the question in your comment)

Comment: thanks, vhdl seems to be very appropiated. I am working on a similar but very simple language with "ports" and signals like: value1.change.connect.value2.set and should mean value2 = value1 . it is longer than mathematical way but i hope it will more far more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you want, but Artificial Intelligence Markup Language or simply AIML is something that you should consider.

The only problem I see with this language is that it is not popular thus there aren't many compilers for it.

---

Here is an example of AIML.

Code from tutorials point :

```
<aiml version = "1.0.1" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
   <category>
      <pattern> HELLO ALICE </pattern>

      <template>
         Hello User!
      </template>

   </category>
</aiml>
```

Result :

```
User: Hello Alice
Bot: Hello User
```

Comment: Thanks, didnt knew about it. I like the idea merging "data" and "code" together. Also something like a databank or like here xml code must be more representive than a poetry-like code. But i also think it must be structure for neurons or cluster of neurons